# How to query from table's view in .Net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql

How to query on table's view in .Net C# web application ?

for example, here [View_App_Academic] is my table view. My code is listed below. under db scheme, I am not able to see the view due to my user privilege.

```
string strquery = "select * from [dbo].[View_App_Academic] where recruitment_id=" + 
RecruitDropDownList.Text + " and ref_no='" + RefDropDownList.Text + "'";

SqlCommand objCMD = new SqlCommand(strquery, conn);
```

Comment: 1) You should use parametrized queries to avoid sql injection 2) Are you sure your view name is correct? 3) Is `recruitment_id` a number and `ref_no` a varchar?

Comment: On which line of your posted code do you get the error?

Comment: The error is about the dbo.View_App_Academic, actually it is my table view.

Comment: 4) Are you sure you're pointing to the correct database?

Comment: It is in my ASP.NET c# web application code be hide program.

Comment: yes, I can make a query to my table, but it is not work when querying my table view.

Comment: I got this error " Invalid object name 'dbo.View_App_Academic' "

Comment: Open the view, I have another unseen table. Is it possible because of my privilege? but I can still use the view on Sqlserver.

Comment: do you have access to the Database.. are you sure that you have the correct spelling of the view..?

Comment: Yes, sure. the spelling  is correct. probably the permission on db user account.

Comment: debug and watch strQuery, copy it to sql management studio and try to execute it directly there to see anything wrong

Comment: The below is my connection string. Does anything wrong regarding the table view?

<add name="ConnectString" connectionString="Data Source=sqltest;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: do you encounter error when you execute the query straightaway using sql management studio? if not, there must be something wrong with your connection or so, otherwise refresh your DB (to make sure the view is still there, not deleted by someone else) at the management studio and check your security settings to see you have permission to execute

Comment: Yes, there has a hidden table which I couldn't see. I have contacted the DBA to reedit my permission in order to see the hidden table.

Comment: SQL injection - http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameterized query always.
  Remove [dbo] from your query, you don't need to add [dbo] because it is default database schema.
  Change your code to this.

```
string strquery = "select * from View_App_Academic where recruitment_id=@recruitment_id and ref_no=@ref_no";

SqlCommand objCMD = new SqlCommand(strquery, conn);
objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recruitment_id", RecruitDropDownList.Text);
objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ref_no",RefDropDownList.Text);
SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
myAdapter.SelectCommand = objCMD;

DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: **+1**: for answering using parameterized